# How do I make use of spaces in a for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

My goal with this program is to

- Obtain a word with more than 5 letters from the console.
- Verify that an empty String was not entered and that the word has
  more than five letters.
- Enter a number greater than 2 and less than 5 for the trunk length.
- Verify that the number meets the requirements.
- Convert the word to all capitals.
- Determine if the word has an even or odd number of letters.
- If it is even, the tree will start with two letters on top and then
  increase the number of letters on each row by 2. The trunk will be
  made up of the two middle letters of the word and the number of rows
  will match the trunk length.
- If it is odd, the tree will start with one letter on top and then
  increase the number of letters on each row by 2. The trunk will be
  made up of the three middle letters of the word and the number of
  rows will match the trunk length.

The goal output is for an even number of letters:

```
      CH 
     CHRI
    CHRIST
   CHRISTMA
  CHRISTMAST
 CHRISTMASTRE
CHRISTMASTREES
      MA
      MA
      MA
```

The goal output is for an odd number of letters:

```
      C
     CHR
    CHRIST
   CHRISTMA
  CHRISTMASTR
 CHRISTMASTREE
      TMA
      TMA
      TMA
```

Here is the code I used:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

// Obtain a word with more than 5 letters from the console
System.out.print("Enter a word with more than 5 letters: ");
String theWord = input.nextLine();

// Verify that an empty String was not entered and that the 
word has more than five letters
if (theWord.isEmpty() || theWord.length() <= 5) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a non-empty word with more than 
5 letters.");
    return;
}

// Enter a number greater than 2 and less than 5 for the trunk 
length
System.out.print("Enter a number greater than 2 and less than 5 
for the trunk length: ");
int trunkLength = input.nextInt();

// Verify that the number meets the requirements
if (trunkLength <= 2 || trunkLength >= 5) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a number greater than 2 " + 
                       "and less than 5 for the trunk length.");
    return;
}

// Convert the word to all capitals
String theWord2 = theWord.toUpperCase();

// Determine if the word has an even number of letters
if (theWord2.length() % 2 == 0) {
    String space = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < theWord2.length(); i += 2) {
        String twoLetters = theWord2.substring(i, i + 2);
        space += twoLetters;
        System.out.println(space);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < trunkLength; j++) {
        int centerIndex = theWord2.length() / 2;
        char firstCenterLetter = theWord2.charAt(centerIndex - 1);
        char secondCenterLetter = theWord2.charAt(centerIndex);
        System.out.println(firstCenterLetter + "" 
                             + secondCenterLetter);
    }
}

// Determine if the word has an odd number of letters
if (theWord2.length() % 2 != 0) {
    for (int p = 0; p < theWord2.length(); p += 2) {
        String letters = theWord2.substring(0, p + 1);
        System.out.println(letters);
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < trunkLength; k++) {
        int centerIndex = theWord2.length() / 2;
        char firstCenterLetter = theWord2.charAt(centerIndex - 1);
        char middleCenterLetter = theWord2.charAt(centerIndex);
        char lastCenterLetter = theWord2.charAt(centerIndex + 1);
        System.out.println(firstCenterLetter + "" + middleCenterLetter + 
                      "" + lastCenterLetter);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Haven't done this in practice, and not entirely expanding because it seems like a school assignment, but I see an algorithm that can be implemented based on max length of **CHRISTMASTREES** to determine the length of characters to center (so you know where to add spaces), and then although it is a predefined/hard-coded amount, you can determine how many characters to show from `CHRISTMASTREES` in each line based on the index of the char and the line you are at. Pseudocode, but something like `if line is 1 show first 2 chars, if line is 2 show first 4, etc...`

Comment: based on the code, I am thinking the widest your tree can be is inputString.length, thus, you can calculate the amount of leading spaces you want to pad each string with (half of inputString.length - half of the calculated String to display)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the white-space padding really only needs to be calculated once and its value would then be decremented as the tree is built. Its overall value would of course depend upon whether or not the supplied string length is either **even** or **odd** since the number of characters the tree starts with is also dependent upon that fact (*two* for even and *one* for odd). With this in mind the initial white-space padding calculation would be something like:

```
int wordLength = word.length();
boolean wordLengthIsEven = (wordLength % 2 == 0);
int padding = wordLengthIsEven ? (wordLength / 2) - 1 : (wordLength / 2);
```

To initialize `padding`, a [Ternary Operator](https://www.baeldung.com/java-ternary-operator) is used to provide a value dependent upon a Even or Odd string length. In order to maintain center and because a string is even, the length of that string is divided by 2 and then 1 is removed from that division result since the Tree would start with two characters. However if the supplied string length is odd, the length of that string is merely divided by 2 since the Tree would start with only one character.

**Just another way:**

I think a decent way to do this task is to build the Tree first as a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) object, then display it as a string in Console. Below is an example putting the above in practice. Be sure to read all the removable comments in code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

/* - Obtain a word with more than 5 letters from the console.
   - Verify that an empty String was not entered and that the 
     word has more than five letters.
   - Convert the word to all capitals.              */
        
// Variable to hold the System's newline character sequence:
final String ls = System.lineSeparator();
        
// Get the string to make into a Tree from User:
String word = "";
while (word.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print("Enter a word with 6 characters or more: -> ");
    word = input.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase();
    // Validate...
    if(!word.matches(".{6,}")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry! (" + word + ") - Try again...\n");
        word = "";
    }
}
        
/* - Enter a number greater than 2 and less than 5 for the trunk length.
   - Verify that the number meets the requirements.     
   - ALSO ADDED: If nothing is supplied then the trunk length is auto-
     calculated. This feature can be removed if desired.             */
        
// Get the Trunk Length from User:
String trunkHeight = "";
while (trunkHeight.isEmpty()) {
     System.out.println("Enter a the number of lines for trunk length (3 or 4).");
     System.out.println("If nothing is supplied then it will be auto-calculated.");
     System.out.print("Desired Trunk Length: -> ");
     trunkHeight = input.nextLine().trim();
     if (trunkHeight.isEmpty()) { 
         break; 
     }
     // Validate:
     if (!trunkHeight.matches("[34]")) {
         System.out.println("Invalid Trunk Length Supplied! (" + trunkHeight 
                           + ") - Try again..." + ls);
         trunkHeight = "";
     }
}
        
// - Determine if the word has an even or odd number of letters.
int wordLength = word.length();
boolean wordLengthIsEven = (wordLength % 2 == 0);
        
/* Determine the trunk letters required based on either even
   or odd letter count of the supplied word (or string).
   `Ternary Operator` is used for this along with the 
   `String#substring()` method:                         */
String trunkLetters = (wordLengthIsEven ? word.substring((wordLength / 2) - 1, 
                              ((wordLength / 2)  + 1)) : word.substring((wordLength / 2) - 1, 
                              ((wordLength / 2) + 2)));
        
/* Determine the initial amount of white-space padding required to 
   start the tree. We do this by taking the supplied string length 
   and dividing it by 2. Because an even String length starts with 
   two letters, we subtract 1 from the division result and because 
   an odd String length starts with one letter, we subtract nothing 
   from the division result. Again, `Ternary Operator` is used here 
   to determine results for even or odd:                 */
int padding = wordLengthIsEven ? (wordLength / 2) - 1 : (wordLength / 2);
        
/* Retrieve the required letter(s) to start the Tree. The first two
   letters if the supplied string length is even or the very first 
   letter if the supplied string length is odd. Yet again, `Ternary 
   Operator` is used here to determine the number of letters for even 
   or odd:                                               */
String letters = wordLengthIsEven ? word.substring(0, 2) : word.substring(0, 1);
        
/* Build The Tree. The entire Tree will be a single string.
   The `StringBuilder` class is used for this. A newline 
   character sequence is appended to the end of each Tree 
   row.                      */
// The Upper Portion Of The Tree:
        
/* This variable is used for decrementing upon each interation of the
   `while` loop below. It initialized to the start padding required 
   to begin the Tree. It will determine how much white-space padding 
   is required for each iteration.        */
int paddingCount = padding;
        
// This object will hold the actual Tree as a string.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        
/* This varaible will be used to keep track of how many iterations
   it took to build the upper portion of the Tree. Its value will
   be used in a calculation to auto-determine the length of the 
   Trunk later on:   */
int iterationCount = 0;
        
/* Keep looping while `paddingCount` is 0 or greater. Remember,
   padding count starts at a value that was pre-determined and
   held within the earlier initialized `padding` variable:   */
while (paddingCount > -1) {
            
    /* Remember, `letter` was initialized with the required start 
       letters and therefore those will be the first letter(s)
       appended to the StringBuilder object (`sb`). Notice how
       padding is only appended to the beginning of each string 
       row of the StringBuilder object (`sb`). It is only required 
       there to build this Tree.   
            
       If you are developing in a JDK of Java8 to jave10 then the 
       `repeat()` method will not be available to you. You can use:
       `sb.append(String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(paddingCount, " ")))`  */
    sb.append(" ".repeat(paddingCount)).append(letters).append(ls);
            
    /* Now, we add two more characters from the supplied string
       to the `letter` variable but first we make sure that this
       process will not exceed the the the number of characters 
       within that supplied string otherwise the `substring()`
       method will fail when adding the last characters.     */ 
    if ((letters.length() + 2) <= wordLength) {
        letters = word.substring(0, letters.length() + 2);
    }
            
    // Increment the iteration count:
    iterationCount++; 
            
    // Decrement the amount of padding required by 1 for the next row:
    paddingCount--;   
}
// Upper Tree portion is now built:
        
// Build and append the Tree Trunk:
/* Auto-calculate the required trunk length but, only if 
   nothing was supplied as a trunk height earlier, otherwise
   use what was supplied as a trunk height after convertion
   to Integer. Again, `Ternary Operator` is used here to 
   determine which length to use:       */
int trunkLength = (trunkHeight.isEmpty() ? iterationCount / 2 : Integer.parseInt(trunkHeight));
        
/* Give `paddingCount` a new value for trunk white-space padding. 
   Again, depending upon whether the supplied string length is 
   either an even or odd value. And again, `Ternary Operator` is
   used for this:                  */
paddingCount = wordLengthIsEven ? padding : padding - 1;
       
// Loop while `trunkLength` is greater than 0:
while (trunkLength > 0) {
            
    /* Remember, `trunkLetters` was initialized with the required  
       trunk letters earlier on. Notice how padding is only appended 
       to the beginning of each trunk string row of the StringBuilder 
       object (`sb`). It is only required there to build this Tree.   
            
       If you are developing in a JDK of Java8 to jave10 then the 
       `repeat()` method will not be available to you. You can use:
       `sb.append(String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(paddingCount, " ")))`  */
    sb.append(" ".repeat(paddingCount)).append(trunkLetters).append(ls);
            
    // Decrement `trunkLength` by 1 on this iteration:
    trunkLength--;  
}
        
// The overall Tree:
String tree = sb.toString();
        
// Display the Tree in Console:
System.out.println(tree);
```

Comment: You are the goat my friend.